# Searching zipped folders

Tags: powershell, pscx

Is it possible to search zipped folders for a specific file name like this?

```
gci $pathContainingZippedFolders -rec | ?{$_ -like "filename"}
```

or

```
gci $pathContainingZippedFolders -rec | ?{$_ -match "filename"}
```

Edit: I forgot to include that I was not able to do so using the above oneliners.

Edit2: I understand the pscx can be used, but I am not sure how to do that.

Edit3: I think this should work better in normal cases, but still failing to read inside the zip file(s). I will try pscx module and post an update sometime today.

```
gci $pathContainingZippedFolders -rec | %{$_ -match "filename"}
```

Comment: @JPBlanc, I have tested it. I mentioned it in the edit. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't get it to work like that.  I can get this to work:

```
$search = "test.txt"
$sa = new-object -com shell.application
gci *.zip |%{
$path = resolve-path $_
if (($sa.namespace("$path").items() |
 select -expand name)  -contains $search){$_} 
}
```